# How to make VS code IntelliSense to show class only attributes not the built object attributes?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have a python class and i want to see only the class attributes in the intellisense suggestions.

```
class car():
    def __init__(self, brand, model, year):
        self.brand = brand
        self.model = model
        self.year = year


c1 = car()
```

when I use the "c1." I see the results like "__ dir__","__ getattribute__" etc. But i want to see only the "brand", "model" & "year" in the intellisense suggestions.

Is there anything to override this behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for displaying "__ dir__", "__ getattribute__" is the "`__init__`" method used in the code, which comes from the file "`builtins.pyi`", and this file also includes "__ dir__", "__ getattribute__"：

[image]

Solution: For example, turn off "`__dir__`": (comment out "`def __dir__(self) -> Iterable[str]: ...`" in "`builtins.pyi`")

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Update:

I tried to turn off the other displays in turn, the following is the code I commented in "`builtins.pyi`":

[image]

There are only four options left: (because this file defines them)

[image]

However, in order to avoid affecting the use of the code, it is not recommended that you change this file. And this does not affect the prompt content "brand", "model", "year" as the first display: (When I use the small box, it will display the preferences, and keep it.)

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Jill Cheng. commenting out "def __dir__(self) -> Iterable[str]: ..." in "builtins.pyi" still shows other built-in methods like "__dict__", "__doc__","__eq__"...in suggestions. But I want to see only "brand", "model" and "year" in the suggestions. Can you please tell me what you did in the last video snippet to achieve this ?

Comment: @Navya Krishna -When I adjust the size of the prompt box to a small box, it seems that it will only display the preferences and keep it.